# Adding fcontext to unconfined application

Tags: rhel, selinux, tomcat

This feels like the most horrid twist of fate ever... A user is having me setup tomEE (`apache-tomee-jaxrs-1.7.4`). This is on a RHEL6 machine.

I've installed from the tarball available from apache's website, and was all prepared to fight `selinux` to get it to work...and then realized that because it's from source... there aren't any default context's applied.

I've never had to work from this end before, usually I'm fighting selinux to GET things to work from a secure state, now I need to take something already working and force it into a confined space, and I'm really not sure where to start.

SO I guess my question is...How to I start building a confined space for something that is currently just set at default unconfined contexts?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have experience in writing custom SELinux policy modules, you can get started using `policygentool` to generate minimal module. This module contains basic file types, labeling rules and the transition to the confined domain.

1. Generate the basic module with `policygentool <name> <executable>`

   The important files are type enforcement (`.te`) and file context (`.fc`) files. Policy rules are in type enforcement file and labeling rules are in file context file. If you need additional labeling rules, define them in the file context file.
2. Compile the policy module using the makefile provided by `selinux-devel` (`/usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile` or similar). Then install the module with `semodule`.

   The rest of the policy can be generated using `audit2allow`. Before running the application, `semanage permissive` can set the domain to permissive mode, allowing normal operation while AVC denial messages are generated.
3. After you got enough logs, use `audit2allow` to generate the rules and append them to the type enforcement file. Also increment the version number there. Then compile and install the new module.
4. If no more AVC denial messages are generated, you can change your domain back to enforcing mode. Otherwise repeat from step 3.